# QT5 font rendering different on various platforms

Tags: windows, macos, qt, fonts

I want to make reproductible tests of some custom widgets renderings. In order to do that, I paint them onto a QImage and save the result as PNG. The output is really different on Windows compared to MacOSX.

I took care of :

- Selecting the same font on all platform (I provide the "TTF" font file and point the code to it)
- Drawing onto a QImage and not a QPixmap, as the documentation says QImage painter is supposed to be platform independant
- I also selected Antialisating and TextAntialiasing hints
- Requesting the font via QFontDatabase::font() so that pointSize is specified and not pixelSize

How can I make sure the rendering is exactly the same on all platforms so that my test runs are reproductible ? In other words, is it maybe possible to force QT5 to use the same font engine on all platforms (for instance freetype) ?

**

I nailed down the issue to a simple rendering test program.
So the code is looks like :

```
QFontDatabase fontDb;
fontDb.addApplicationFont(".../fonts/Vera.ttf");

QImage   result(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
QPainter painter(&result);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);


QBrush background(QColor(205, 205, 205));
painter.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600, background);

QFont font = fontDb.font("Bitstream Vera Sans", "Normal", 10);
painter.setFont(font);

painter.setPen(QColor(0, 0, 0));
painter.drawText(10, 10, "ABCD abcd 01234567");
```

The Bitstream Vera font can be downloaded on fontsquirel.com for instance.

See the result on MacOSX (left) and on Win32 (right), which are very different:

[image]

---

Following answer and comments by N1ghtLight below, and after reading the links he suggested, I changed the code to get the font to :

```
QFont font = fontDb_->font(("Bitstream Vera Sans", "Normal", -1);

qreal screenDPI  = QApplication::primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch();
qreal RENDER_DPI = 72;

int pixelSize = (int)((qreal)10 * screenDPI / RENDER_DPI);
font.setPixelSize(pixelSize);
```

This seems to mostly solve the problem of the font of very different size. At least on MacOSX, the font is exactly 10 pixels high now. On Windows though the font renders much thinner and a bit smaller too. I'm still lost and confused...

Here is the new result (left MacOSX, right Windows). The white scale indicates true 10 pixels size.

[image]

---

Following answer by G_G below I adapted the code (what about Linux ? Mobile platforms ? This gets very complicated...). Now the fonts are 10 pixels in the output on both Windows and MacOSX, still the rending remains very different (still MacOSX on the left, Windows on the right).

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Note that adding the following to qt.conf does not change anything on windows: "[Platforms] WindowsArguments = fontengine=freetype"

Comment: This is also related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641968/use-freetype-on-windows-with-qt5 which as no satisfactory answer

Comment: It your mac a Retina one ?

Comment: No it's a MacMini. Moreover rending to QImage is supposed to be independant of screen resolution, graphics card and so on, according to the QT documentation.

Comment: How about a test with the the freetype itself without qt?

Comment: Alex: in fact this week end I implemented a rendering only using Freetype. And the result is 100% accurate and 100% reproductible across platforms...

Comment: Did you find a solution? How did you work around this issue? It's still present as of Qt 5.6.

Comment: I never could get it to work. For my specific project I ended embedding Cairo and Freetype and use those for rendering to bitmaps instead of the Qt rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

your render DPI variable should be 96 for Windows and 72 for OSX

according to:
http://www.rfwilmut.clara.net/about/fonts.html

> On a Macintosh monitor, the notional resolution is 72 dots-per -inch
>   (dpi), so that a graphic 72 pixels wide would notionally be 1 inch
>   wide - though obviously the actual size would depend on the individual
>   monitor. However it will always print one inch wide.
>
> But on a Windows monitor the resolution is (usually) 96 dpi. This
>   means that though the picture is still 72 pixels wide, it will print
>   at 0.75 inches.

```
QFont font = fontDb_->font(("Bitstream Vera Sans", "Normal", -1);
qreal screenDPI  = QApplication::primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch();

#ifdef WINDOWS
qreal RENDER_DPI = 96;
#else
qreal RENDER_DPI = 72;
#endif

int pixelSize = (int)((qreal)10 * screenDPI / RENDER_DPI);
font.setPixelSize(pixelSize);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer, maybe with sample code ? Especially as I added more code in my question that take care of adjusting the pixel size to the screen DPI.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question, it still does not work.

Comment: @Eric: you should define WINDOWS when compiling under Windows or the compiler will always enter the #else condition, actually reverting to your original code

Comment: of course. I changed WINDOWS by WIN32 in your code to make sure the 96 DPI is used. Thanks.

Comment: and what do you get? can you post the new rendered image(s)? it will be useful to continue investigating the problem

Comment: I did post the new rendering result.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you set size in pixels. You need to use setPointSize() instead.

From the Qt 5 docs:

```
void QFont::setPixelSize(int pixelSize)
```

*Sets the font size to pixelSize pixels.
Using this function makes the font device dependent. Use setPointSize() or setPointSizeF() to set the size of the font in a device independent manner.*

Also, for more info, you can check [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27201) post. This difference happens because of different display density on different OSs. I have experienced such problem myself on one OS X, Windows cross platform project.

---

[Updated] After my additional research, I've found, that current behavior of Qt fonts is just a bug. That's why solution above doesn't work (it worked for Qt 4)
[Here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41846) is described different workarounds to solve this problem. Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping you were true, but no. I changed my code, the font access is now via QFontDatabase::font(fontFamily, fontStyle, 10). The 10 value is a 'pointSize' and not a 'pixelSize' here. The output is still different, my screen capture above still apply. I edited my code above to reflect this.

Comment: How about calling of "setPointSize" ? Qt Docs suggests to call exactly it.

Comment: I've just checked myself on OS X and Windows, it looks like the fonts are really different. Maybe, that is some kind of bug, or some additional global settings is needed. In any case your initial source code contained the violation of Qt Docs that was 100% the reason of such issue, for example, for Qt 4. Here it's some another factor.

Comment: Eric, I've updated my answer after my additional research. Also, it's not good practice to change the initial source code in the question after people found real issue in it and marked in the answer, because my answer started looks pretty strange.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this. this will generate an image with the text which you will write. I using this code.

```
QPixmap photo;
QFont qfont;
QPainter painter;
QString txt;

QImage img(x,y,QImage::Format_RGB32);

painter.begin(&img);
img.fill(0xffffffff);
painter.drawPixmap(0,0,x,y,photo);

qfont.setFamily("Sampige");
qfont.setPixelSize(28);
painter.setFont(qfont);
txt = QString::fromUtf8("ನಮಸ್ಕಾರ");
painter.drawText(1,26,txt);
painter.end();
img.save("abcd.jpg");
```

Comment: You are missing the point entirely. My sample code already demonstrate how to save text into an image. However the result is not consistent across platforms (MacOSX / Windows).