# How is the fontsize defined in Qt4?

Tags: qt

It sounds simple but how is the fontsize, which can be set with [setPointSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#setPointSize) defined in Qt4? A point is 1/72 inch but if I compare to 
[glyph metrics from FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step2.html)

[image: FT glyph metric]

Is it the max_advance_height, the advance between two lines or the distance between the highest and lowest point (the maximum ascender - descender)?

If I create a QLabel and `setPointSize` to 75 I get the following result:

[image: ABC 100 points]

My screen has 96x96 dpi which should result in 75/72*96 = 100 pixels. But measured the B, for example is 70 pixels in height.

Comment: OSX and Windows have different DPI. I don't know which dpi render you use, but in calculation maybe is not 72 but 96. More on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25929628/2050745)

Comment: In short, it isn't defined in or by Qt.  The size of a font is more closely related to the minimum base line separation required for successive lines of text to be legible.  Some further useful info [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly).